# What's it called when someone starts a well-known saying but doesn't finish it?

Tags: single-word-requests, writing-style

Often times in a TV show that I watch and love, Supernatural, the big bads use quotes and sayings to further their point. For example, Crowley, the current King of Hell at the time, replied to Dean, the protagonist, (in response to an insult)

> Sticks and stones...

It's implied that he was telling Dean that his words cannot hurt him, but I would like to know if this type of speech or writing has an actual name to it?

In another moment, also by Crowley to Dean, he says

> What's the line? Saving people, hunting things...

This is a saying directly related to the show, as their family motto is

> Saving people, hunting things, the family business

At first, I thought the reason for them not saying the full quote was due to copyright and legal issues, as it wasn't only Crowley that spoke like this. But now, I'm thinking that in the writers' heads, maybe it's just a speech technique centered around inference, and I could be overthinking this... I'm asking if it has a name because I'd like to research it a little and flawlessly incorporate this technique into my writing.

Comment: The previous answer is well worth reading.